# Struts 2 FileUpload not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, file-upload, struts2

I have a struts 2 application where 2 pages have struts file upload. One works perfectly while the other just wont work. I gives me "Invalid field value for field "secImage".

**Here is the code for JSP**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

    <s:form action="Test" method="POST" style="width:90%;">
           Another form here......
    </s:form>
    <s:form action="Test" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <s:push value="secVul">
            <s:hidden name="vulId" />
            <s:hidden name="scanHistory.scanId" />
            <s:textfield name="protocol" label="Protocol" style="width: 80%;" />
            <s:textarea name="description" label="Description" style="width: 80%;" />
            <s:textarea name="solution" label="solution" />
            <more form elements here>sdfasdfasdfasd

            <s:file name="secImage" label="Image to Upload" size="40"/>
            <s:submit value="Add/Update" align="center"/>
        </s:push>
    </s:form>
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the struts configuration**

```
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
<param name="maximumSize">909715200</param>
<param name="allowedTypes">
text/xml,application/octet-stream,image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <action name="Test" method="saveOrUpdate" class="com.Test">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listVulsMGR</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/secVuls.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/pages/secVuls.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

**Action Class Code:**

```
public class Test extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Test>, Preparable,ServletRequestAware {

private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ListVulsActions.class);


private File secImage;
private String secImageContentType;
private String secImageFileName;


private HashMap userFilters = new HashMap();
public Test() {


}

public String saveOrUpdate() {
    try {

        ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        String filePath = context.getInitParameter("UploadDirectory");
        logger.debug("Server path:" + filePath);
        logger.debug("this.secImageFileName " + this.secImageFileName);

        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.secImageFileName);

        FileUtils.copyFile(this.secImage, fileToCreate);

}           
        addActionMessage("successfully added/updated.");
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error in Test", ex);
        addActionError("Error occured in Test. Please contact your administrator.\n" + ex.getMessage());
        return ERROR;
    }

}

public File getSecImage() {
            System.out.println(secImage.getName());
    return secImage;
}

/**
 * @param secImage the secImage to set
 */
public void setSecImage(File secImage) {
    System.out.println(secImage.getName());
    this.secImage = secImage;
}

/**
 * @return the secImageContentType
 */
public String getSecImageContentType() {
    System.out.println(secImageContentType);
    return secImageContentType;
}

/**
 * @param secImageContentType the secImageContentType to set
 */
public void setSecImageContentType(String secImageContentType) {
    System.out.println(secImageContentType);
    this.secImageContentType = secImageContentType;
}

/**
 * @return the secImageFileName
 */
public String getSecImageFileName() {
    System.out.println(secImageFileName);
    return secImageFileName;
}

/**
 * @param secImageFileName the secImageFileName to set
 */
public void setSecImageFileName(String secImageFileName) {
    System.out.println(secImageFileName);
    this.secImageFileName = secImageFileName;
}

@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

    this.servletRequest = servletRequest;



}
```

---

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Would appreciate any help/hints

--

Comment: which one os working and which one is not working? any error/exception you are getting for that?

Comment: Hi Umesh. The code in my initial post is the one not working. There is no error in the log files of Apache logs. I only get ""Invalid field value for field "secImage"...in the action error messages. Other than that, every thing works smooth.

Comment: Also in the example above I have missed the setter/getter methods for the file and content type which are actually there. I am not sure why I get the **invalid field value error**. This happens even before my action method is called. Seems Struts is validating fields before calling the Action class. But I am not sure where and why is it rejecting the uploaded file.

Comment: You will have a `invalid field value error` if secImage is not a `File`. http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-TypeConversionErrorHandling. Are you sure that you are calling correctly the action in the form? I see that you have `saveOrUpdateVulMGR` action in the form and you show another action in the struts.xml file.

Comment: Hi Pigueiras, Sorry the action name was wrongly put in the XML file. It is actually **saveOrUpdateVulMGR**. I have double checked the file is valid JPG or PNG file which is in the allowed contents in struts.xml file. Also the getter/setter methods for file name 
and content type get the correct file name and content type

Comment: public String getSecImageContentType() {
        System.out.println(secImageContentType);
        return secImageContentType;
    }
    public void setSecImageContentType(String secImageContentType) {
        S.o.p(secImageContentType);
        this.secImageContentType = secImageContentType;
    }
    public String getSecImageFileName() {
        System.out.println(secImageFileName);
        return secImageFileName;
    }

    public void setSecImageFileName(String secImageFileName) {
        System.out.println(secImageFileName);
        this.secImageFileName = secImageFileName;
    }

Comment: I think you can edit your own post if you want to add more information I think :D. Can you put your entire form and action in the first post?

Comment: Edited/Corrected the code now. Thanks

Comment: What are the hidden elements for? They have no value (only name).

Comment: They are pushed (push tag) and used at server end for editing/updating.

Answer (score 0):

take another varible name is `<s:file name`'s type file type generate setter and getter 
`private File secImage; getter &setters()` doing operations on `FileUtils.copyFile(this.secImage, fileToCreate);`

Comment: Thank you maabujji.. It worked fine after adding a new variable. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 - Check form line in your JSP must contain: **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

ex:`<s:form theme="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`
*NOTE: If your JSP extends, the parent also need to contain that line.*

2 - Check you defined setter and getter method's properly. [struts2 FileUpload Problem](http://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html)

Hope this help.